# Point Set Topology Puzzle

Tags: general-topology

Choose A, a subset of some topological space X. If we are given the closure and complement operations, how many distinct subsets of X can we create? How can we choose A to maximize this number? I believe the maximum is 10, but I'm curious what other people think. Also, this problem is sort of fun...

Comment: This is a problem in John Kelly's "General Topology." I believe there are 14 possible sets. I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Is the Kuratowski's closure-complement problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_closure-complement_problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is $14$; one set which achieves this number is
$$
S = (\mathbb Q\cap(0,1))\cup\{3/2\}\cup[2,3)\cup(3,4],
$$
as you can check (under the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, of course). For more details, see the solution to problem 9 in http://www.northeastern.edu/ckottke/3150/ps5_solns.pdf. That solution assumes that the topological space is a metric space but the same proof works for topological spaces in general.

Comment: Thanks, I realize now why it is 14 and not 10. A boundary point of A need not be a boundary point of the interior of A.